# Can't scan to a shared folder but can write to it from computer - windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-sharing

I have a Toshiba network scanner/copier that is configured to send scanned files to a shared folder.
It was working fine when the shared folder was on a windows server 2003 computer.

I installed Windows server 2012 on a new computer and set up a shared folder.
Now, I can access that shared folder from any computer and read/write/delete files without a problem.

When I configured the scanner to send scanned files to that shared folder, it could access the shared folder but creates 0-size files.
And the scan log of the scanner shows a message: "Failed to create file"
The documentation of the scanner suggested to tweak the settings related to SMB to be: "Digital signature isn't done for the communication for the server"
Again, still works with 2003 but not 2012.
What might be the problem with WS 2012 sharing?

Answer (score 0):

Use Group Policy to set `Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Options\Microsoft network server: Digitally sign communications (always)` to `Disabled`

This will prevent the server requiring SMB signing, which the copier cannot do.

Comment: I found this option was already disabled. So, this is not the problem.

Comment: Also, the older versions of SMB are also supported in the server (SMB1 and SMB2).